# Manipulate files older than X

Tags: windows

I've searched a lot how to delete files older than a number X  given but I've only found questions too old to trust.

I have directory filled with files .zip those files are created  to make space but one day i won't have anymore space so i've thought that i can choose a number of days (X) to choose when i want to delete some files and which files i want to delete. At the moment i'm searching for a way to select the files from a folder given that are older than Today - X and tha tdelete them.

```
void fCamImgCanc(long pThreadId)
{
ULARGE_INTEGER rFreeBytesAvailable, rTotalNumberOfBytes, rTotalNumberOfFreeBytes;
if(sys.Logs.CamImgSave && sys.Logs.ImageSMod == 1)
{
if (::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx ("C:\\S\\LOGBOOK\\Cam\\Logfold", &rFreeBytesAvailable, &rTotalNumberOfBytes, &rTotalNumberOfFreeBytes))
{
  if (rTotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart < ((rTotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart * sys.LogB.FreeSpaceOnDisk) / 100))    //if disk size < __% delete the older day
  {                                                                                                         
    do
    {
            //Date of the oldest group of files         > Today -  sys.LogB.OlderThanD setted for example to 13
      if("C:\\S\\LOGBOOK\\Cam\\Logfold\\FilenameData" > Today - sys.LogB.OlderThanD)   
      {
        DeleteFile("C:\\S\\LOGBOOK\\Cam\\Logfold"); 
      }
    }while(rTotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart < ((rTotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart * sys.LogB.FreeSpaceOnDisk) / 100)); //free space till we have the space that we need
  }
fAddOnZip("C:\\S\\LOGBOOK\\Cam");   
}
}
else  //ImageSMod = 0 ->  Relative "save of the images of the lot and at the next lot delete of them"
{
 DO OTHER THINGS
}
}
```

I've got the delete function and the zip function yet

Comment: this doesn't look like C.

Comment: @Ôrel this looks like windows api for c

Comment: you have a lot of unescaped backslashes

Comment: Why are you using the scope-resolution operator in the call to `::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`? - The :: operator is used for selecting a local variable instead of a global one. Do you have more than 1 instance of the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` symbol present in the project?

Comment: yes have more than one instance... this is only a little part of a  very big OS

Comment: `::` is C++, not C, or I miss something.

Comment: it isn't enitrely written by me so i think that it is a mashup of c and c++... cause some things usually doesn't exist in a normal program C and other usually are written like this in  a C++ program...isn't my fault sorry

Comment: `system("forfiles ...")` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Comment: i'm looking for something to concatenete to this path "C:\\S\\LOGBOOK\\Cam\\Logfold\\FilenameData" instead of FilenameData to poit to a group of files older than Today - X

Comment: The title and tags should be changed to C++. The `::`Scope operator is C++, even if C styles are otherwise used.

Comment: Isn't my fault sorry but if I change from c to c++ noone will be able to understand why they are responding to something written in c++ but with the style of c...I think that maybe is more clear like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate files in a directory with [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew).

Get the current time with [GetSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) (and convert to "file time" with [SystemTimeToFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetofiletime)).

Do the approriate math to get the timestamp from N days ago.  It's all based on 100ns units.  (10 million of those equals "one second").

Then DeleteFile to actually delete the file.

And some helper functions from the Windows SDK [to concatenate paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchappend).  Link with `PatchCch.lib`.

Here's some code to get you started. If you invoke:

```
delete_all_old_files_in_directory(L"C:\\Users\\YourName\\Downloads", 7);
```

It will delete everything from the Downloads folder older than a week.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <PathCch.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "pathcch")

void delete_all_old_files_in_directory(const wchar_t* dir, DWORD dwDays)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st = { 0 };
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH * 2 + 2];
    BOOL succeeded = TRUE;
    uint64_t filetimeNow = 0;
    uint64_t filetimeCompare = 0;
    uint64_t delta;
    HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW data = { 0 };

    // dont't try to delete directories or special files
    const DWORD dwMask = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN;

    GetSystemTime(&st);
    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, (FILETIME*)&filetimeNow);

    delta = 10000000ULL * dwDays * 60 * 60 * 24;

    filetimeCompare = filetimeNow - delta;

    StringCchCopy(szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath), dir);
    PathCchAppend(szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath), L"*.*");

    h = FindFirstFile(szPath, &data);
    succeeded = (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    while (succeeded)
    {
        uint64_t fileTimeThisFile = *(uint64_t*)(&data.ftCreationTime);
        wchar_t szDeletePath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
        StringCchCopy(szDeletePath, ARRAYSIZE(szDeletePath), dir);
        PathCchAppend(szDeletePath, ARRAYSIZE(szDeletePath), data.cFileName);

        if ((fileTimeThisFile < filetimeCompare) && !(data.dwFileAttributes & dwMask))
        {
            wprintf(L"Deleting: %ls\n", szDeletePath);
            DeleteFile(szDeletePath);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Keeping: %ls\n", szDeletePath);
        }
        succeeded = FindNextFile(h, &data);
    }

    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FindClose(h);
        h = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    delete_all_old_files_in_directory(L"C:\\Users\\YourName\\Downloads", 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214645/discussion-on-answer-by-selbie-how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-with-c).